# Failed Cognito Federated Sign-In with Google

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, google-signin

I am working on a project where we have existing Google Sign-in and we would like to convert to AWS Cognito so we can get username and password authentication as well as other social logins such as Facebook in the near future. In a feature branch of our API, we have working Cognito authentication via JWT. *My current issue is exchanging the Google authentication response payload for Cognito's JWT.*

In our JavaScript, I am able to get a Google authentication response object that has the `tokenId` field. It is my understanding that I should be able to exchange that with Cognito for their JWT that I can use for interacting with my API. I have the Google app created and configured in the Cognito User Pool.

What has been frustrating in trying to figure this out is that all the documentation seems to focus on new apps or just on the hosted UI for Cognito. I have dug through [GitHub issues](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3818) and [blog posts](https://dev.to/dabit3/the-complete-guide-to-user-authentication-with-the-amplify-framework-2inh) that claim this should be easy. I'm hopeful I'm missing something easy.

For reference, here is the code I have to sign in with Cognito and extract the JWT.

```js
const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
dispatch(addToken(user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken));
```

This is the library we've used for Google Sign-in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use third party tokens on your client side and exchange them with Cognito for **Userpool** tokens.

You can exchange client side third party tokens for an **Identity pool** token.

I think this page on common scenarios might help you visualise the processes
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-scenarios.html

You probably need to do one of two things;

- Setup an identity pool and then exchange your google token for an identity pool token. Keep in mind an identity pool can only provide authorisation (not authentication), so if you need Userpool data out of Cognito this is not the option for you.
- Change your approach so that Cognito does the exchange with Google. It will return you a code which you then exchange with your Userpool Token endpoint for Userpool tokens.

Answer (score -1):

Have you configured Google as a federated IdP in your Cognito user pool? https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-google-social-identity-provider/

Comment: Yes, I have it configured.

Comment: To add more color (I was outside for my first reply), I have Cognito with username and password working with a custom form and all the connecting JavaScript. I also have Google authentication working with all the connecting JavaScript. The link I’m missing is taking that Google authentication and turning it into a Cognito authentication.